# Run code if a full year has elasped

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to send an email to a user every year based on the date on which their account was created.

I currently have code for checking if a number of months have passed since they last logged in and was wondering if it could be modified, the code is shown below:

```
public static int GetMonthsBetween(DateTime from, DateTime to)
{
    if (from > to) return GetMonthsBetween(to, from);

    var monthDiff = Math.Abs((to.Year * 12 + (to.Month - 1)) - (from.Year * 12 + (from.Month - 1)));

    if (from.AddMonths(monthDiff) > to || to.Day < from.Day)
    {
        return monthDiff - 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return monthDiff;
    }
}

if (GetMonthsBetween(lastLoginDate, currentDate) >= 4)
```

I only want send the email when a full year has elapsed since the creation date,  how do I go about doing this?

Comment: It's obvious that months are not granular enough.  You have to go down to the day of year.

Comment: `>= 12`.......?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this way to check whether year crossed or not, kindly have a look.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime from = DateTime.Parse("23/3/2016 5:15:14 PM");
        DateTime to = DateTime.Now;

        bool isYearCrossed = IsYearCrossed(from, to);
    }

    public static bool IsYearCrossed(DateTime from, DateTime to)
    {
        if (to.AddYears(-1) >= from)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Comment: is it possible to modify your code so that it only evaluates as true when the number of years is exactly a year so where year = 1 or year = 2 and so on? I don't want it to be true if the number of years is 1 year and 2 months

Comment: You can do like this int diffMonth = ((((from.Year - to.Year) * 12) + from.Month - to.Month) * -1); check it out

Comment: how would I turn this into a boolean?

Comment: essentially what I need is a version of your previous code but only returning true if a full year has passed since the account create date for example if I created the account on 23/03/2016 the code would run on 23/03/2017

Answer (score 10):

It seems to me that the right approach is to change your design - instead of asking for the months between one date and another, you should add the relevant number of months to your original `DateTime`. You don't need a helper method for that at all:

```
if (lastLoginDate.AddMonths(4) >= currentDate)
```

Or for a year:

```
if (lastLoginDate.AddYears(1) >= currentDate)
```

There's no type in .NET representing a "period" of days, months etc - you might want to consider my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) library for that. At that point you could have:

```
private static readonly Period LoginExpiredPeriod = ...;

...

// Assuming lastLoginDate and currentDate are LocalDate values
if (lastLoginDate + period >= currentDate)
{
    ...
}
```

You need to be aware of the impact of months and years being variable length though - for example, "Feb 29th 2016 + 1 year" is Feb 28th 2017 in Noda Time... but you *may* want to use March 1st 2017, for example. Be careful, basically.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `AddYears` method of `DateTime` to add one year to the last login date and check the calculated date with the current date via calling `Date`.

If both dates are the same one year is passed.

```
var newDate = lastLoginDate.AddYears(1);
if(DateTime.Now.Date <= newDate.Date)
{
  //one year passed
}
```